# Удалить записи timestamp в базе данных у которых предыдущее значение отличается на секунду

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Подскажите как удалить записи в поле где хранится метка времени UNIX в которых предыдущее значение отличаются на одну секунду.

Например в такой таблице нужно удалить записи поля date, которые заканчиваются на 
**601**, **841**, **081**

В примере обозначил записи которые нужно удалить.

Хотел это сделать средствами базы, никак не могу сообразить что нужно делать, даже не знаю возможно ли так. 
В крайнем случае можно и циклом в PHP.

[image: Пример]

Comment: если идут подряд 601 602 603 604 605 606 - все удалять кроме 601?

Comment: В подряд так идти не будет, поскольку при сохранении есть окно только две секунды, типа так  if(date()%120 >= 0 && date()%120 <= 1)
{
Сохраняем в базу
}  А так да, нужно оставить только одну любую запись из перечисленных вами

Comment: Там вместо date() будет time(). Ошибся в спешке.

Comment: `delete d1.* from dtest d1
  join dtest d2
    on d2.date=d1.date-1` предварительно проверить те ли записи заменив delete на select

Comment: Проверив заменить на select. На первый взгляд все отлично, спасибо большое. Это надо же, на вид такой простой запрос, а я ломал голову целый час, так и не додумался. Эх, мне еще учиться и учиться.

Comment: Учится не страшно и не стыдно. Стыдно быть неучем и корчить из себя всезнайку. Я, например, тоже не знал что можно джойнить таблицы сами в себя, за что спасибо @Mike.

Comment: Есть еще удобная тема в mysql - replace into, вместо Insert into. Очень удобно и не надо будет запускать доп. запрос на удаление данных http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/REPLACE.html